# I am unable to install Rails on Cloud9 IDE

Tags: cloud9-ide

I am getting the following error
using ruby 1.9.3

> gem install rails --version=4.0.0
>   /opt/rh/ruby193/root/usr/share/rubygems/rubygems/specification.rb:541:in `read': Permission denied - /usr/libexec/openshift/cartridges/c9-0.1/root/lib/ruby/gems/specifications/multi_json-1.8.4.gemspec (Errno::EACCES)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I got from support:

"That is indeed a deployment regression that went with our latest release that's causing this issue and break new workspace creations. 
We have a fix for it that should be in production in 12 hours from now.

However, a workaround would be to separate your ruby workspace's environment from our shared space installation:

edit ~/.bashrc adding the line to the end of the file (using nano or vim):

`export GEM_PATH=$HOME/lib/ruby/gems`

Then:

`$ source ~/.bashrc`

`$ gem install rails -v 3.2.16`

`$ bundle install`